# AngularJS Ion.RangeSlider not updating the min & max dynamically on change of a particalar button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, rangeslider

I have a directive for the slider which is interanaly using
 ionRangeSlider.  On Click of button the mix and max values are changed
 but it is not updating in the directive.I added the watch function in
 link.

Below is the slider directive

```
var app = angular.module('ionSlider',[]);
app.directive('ionslider',function($timeout){
return{
    restrict:'AE',
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope:{
    options:'='
    },
    template:'<div id="{{id}}" ></div>',
    replace:true,
    link:function($scope, $element, attrs, ngModel) {
       // //function init(){
        var init =function(){
            $element.ionRangeSlider({
                min: $scope.options.min,
                max: $scope.options.max,
                type: $scope.options.type,
                prefix: $scope.options.prefix,
                maxPostfix: $scope.options.maxPostfix,
                prettify: $scope.options.prettify,
                hasGrid: $scope.options.hasGrid,
                gridMargin: $scope.options.gridMargin,
                postfix:$scope.options.postfix,
                from:$scope.options.from,
                step:$scope.options.step,
                hideMinMax:$scope.options.hideMinMax,
                hideFromTo:$scope.options.hideFromTo,
                onChange:$scope.options.onChange
            });
        };
        init();
      //OnChange
     var    update = function()
        {
         $element.ionRangeSlider ({
              min: $scope.options.min,
                max: $scope.options.max,
                type: $scope.options.type,
                prefix: $scope.options.prefix,
                maxPostfix: $scope.options.maxPostfix,
                prettify: $scope.options.prettify,
                hasGrid: $scope.options.hasGrid,
                gridMargin: $scope.options.gridMargin,
                postfix:$scope.options.postfix,
                from:$scope.options.from,
                step:$scope.options.step,
                hideMinMax:$scope.options.hideMinMax,
                hideFromTo:$scope.options.hideFromTo,
                onChange:$scope.options.onChange
         });

        };
    //watch
      $scope.$watch('options', function(value) {
        $timeout(function(){ update(); }); 

      });
     }
    }
});
```

The HTML code for the same is as below :

```
    <td  style="width:30%;" class="normal_row"><span><input ng-model="ldcInput.value" type="text" id={{key}} ionslider options="{'min':ldcInput.minValue,'max':ldcInput.maxValue,'step':ldcInput.step}" ng-change="mathCalculation(ldcInput)"/></span></td>
```

The above slidervalues for min and max are changed based on click of button.   But it is not reflected in slider.Please let me know where i am going wrong in the directive.

Answer (score 1):

Since ion.RangeSlider is injected by jQuery you cannot update any of its attributes by calling the injection again.

I improved an already existing directive by adding updatable attributes and some missing ones to this fork, which will solve your issue. For an example on how to use it pleaase refer to the github page.

```
/**
 * Created by Abdullah on 9/19/14.
 * 
 * Modified and enhanced by Juergen Wahlmann on 3/5/15
 */

var app = angular.module('ionSlider',['ngRoute']);


app.directive('ionslider',function($timeout){
return{
    restrict:'E',
    scope:{min:'=',
        max:'=',
        type:'@',
        prefix:'@',
        maxPostfix:'@',
        prettify:'@',
        hasGrid:'@',
        gridMargin:'@',
        postfix:'@',
        step:'@',
        hideMinMax:'@',
        hideFromTo:'@',
        from:'=',
        disable:'=',
        onChange:'=',
        onFinish:'='

    },
    template:'<div></div>',
    replace:true,
    link:function($scope,$element,attrs){
        (function init(){
            $($element).ionRangeSlider({
                min: $scope.min,
                max: $scope.max,
                type: $scope.type,
                prefix: $scope.prefix,
                maxPostfix: $scope.maxPostfix,
                prettify: $scope.prettify,
                hasGrid: $scope.hasGrid,
                gridMargin: $scope.gridMargin,
                postfix:$scope.postfix,
                step:$scope.step,
                hideMinMax:$scope.hideMinMax,
                hideFromTo:$scope.hideFromTo,
                from:$scope.from,
                disable:$scope.disable,
                onChange:$scope.onChange,
                onFinish:$scope.onFinish
            });
        })();
        $scope.$watch('min', function(value) {
            $timeout(function(){ $($element).data("ionRangeSlider").update({min: value}); });
        },true);
        $scope.$watch('max', function(value) {
            $timeout(function(){ $($element).data("ionRangeSlider").update({max: value}); });
        });
        $scope.$watch('from', function(value) {
            $timeout(function(){ $($element).data("ionRangeSlider").update({from: value}); });
        });
        $scope.$watch('disable', function(value) {
            $timeout(function(){ $($element).data("ionRangeSlider").update({disable: value}); });
        });
    }
}
});
```

[ionRangeSlider-Angular-Directive](https://github.com/kashban/ionRangeSlider-Angular-Directive)

Comment: Hey Jurgen - I realise you posted this sometime back. The prettify seems incorrectly named as prettify:'@', instead of prettify:'=' ... in any case I cant seem to get the prettify to fire.

Comment: @Jonathan unfortunately I no longer have access to this project, so I am unable to check or test anything related to it. I hope you get it solved.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I updated my version of iorangeslider and fixed the above issue and all works well now. Thanks for your response!